# FileNotFoundException cannot be resolved to a type when trying to read a .txt file in java

Tags: java

I wrote a program to count the number of a certain letter in a .txt file but I keep getting an error that says FileNotFoundException cannot be resolved to a type.  Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class Count
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

      String phrase;    // a string of characters
      int countBlank;   // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase 
      int length;       // the length of the phrase
      char ch;          // an individual character in the string
  int countA;
  int countE;
  int countS;
  int countT;

  java.io.File file = new java.io.File("counting.txt");
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner (file);

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      phrase = scan.nextLine();
      length = phrase.length();

      // Initialize counts

  while (true)
  { 
  if (phrase.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))

      break;

  else
  {

  countBlank = 0;
  countA = 0;
  countE = 0;
  countS = 0;
  countT = 0;

  for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )   
   { 
   if ( phrase.charAt( i ) == ' ' )

    countBlank++;
    ch = phrase.charAt(i);

       switch (ch)
        {
         case 'a':
         case 'A':  countA++;
                 break;
     case 'e':
     case 'E':  countE++;
         break;
     case 's':
     case 'S':  countS++;
            break;
     case 't':
     case 'T':  countT++;
        break;
      }

 }


    System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
        System.out.println ();

    System.out.println ("Number of A's: " + countA);
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Number of E's: " + countE);
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Number of S's: " + countS);
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Number of T's: " + countT);
    break;
  }     
 }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: The code doesn't compile... Add an import for the `java.io. FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: I did and now it runs.  How do I modify it so that the program reads a .txt file instead of asking for imput

Comment: If using eclipse, try ctrl + shift + o to fill in any missing imports.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the import for [FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html), you can add it like so -

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
```

Or, you might prefer to import the entire `java.io` package with a wildcard

```
import java.io.*;
```

Many IDE(s) can search for the import(s) [and/or] auto-complete, simply go to the end of the word `FileNotFoundException` and try pressing `CTRL-SPACE`.

Comment: Or simply `import java.io.*;`, if other java.io interfaces will be referenced.

Comment: I did and now it runs. How do I modify it so that the program reads a .txt file instead of asking for imput?

Comment: Use the Scanner `inFile` and comment out the `scan`. So `phrase = inFile.nextLine();`

Comment: Thanks I changed that and it reads the file, but the output is wrong.  It prints out the wrong number of letters in the .txt file.  How do I fix that?

Comment: It counts line by line, in what way is it wrong when reading from the file? Also, you've asked three questions here.